# Встроенные алгоритмы java

Tags: java, алгоритм, бинарный-поиск

сейчас изучаю алгоритмику, подскажите, пожалуйста, а в java есть встроенные методы, например такие как бинарный поиск, наверняка же, самые часто используемые алгоритмы должны быть, не заново же программисты каждый раз пишут тот же код бинарного поиска.

Если они есть, то где их взять, я попробовал по наитию, вызвать схожие по названию методы

array. (тут и sort и bin вводил) - нет таких методов, но это говорит только о том, что я что-то не знаю (

Comment: надо не вводить наугда, а смотреть документацию https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html вон и бинарный поиск сразу же, и сортировка

Comment: В яндексе вбиваете в поиск "Работы с массивами java" и изучаете

Answer (score 1):

Конечно есть, например `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch()`
([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte%5B%5D,%20byte)))

В классе Arrays собраны методы, которые помогают работе с массивами. Другие алгоритмы обычно находятся в классах стандартной библиотеки, относящихся к тем структурам данных, которые эти алгоритмы обрабатывают.